# Writing Multiple Variables to one CSV line

Tags: c#, csv, cell

I'm trying to write variables to one line in a CSV file where each variable is in a different cell. My issue is that all of the variables are written to the same cell when trying to use 'append' and 'AppendLine' cant take more than one argument

This is my code:

```
    var NBSref = textBox3.Text;
    var Lenght = textBox1.Text;
    var Width = textBox2.Text;


    string csvpath = "FILE LOCATION";

    StringBuilder csvcontentNew = new StringBuilder();
    csvcontentNew.Append(NBSref + Lenght + Width);  // This is my issue




    //String that will define CSV Location

    File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvcontentNew.ToString());


    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox3.Clear();
```

When I use 'Append' all of the variable data is inserted into my file, but all in the same cell as seen below

[This is what I get from my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTgIi.png)

But this is what I want:

[Ideally what my program would output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1HXV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very name of CSV is giving you the answer: "Comma Separated Value". You need to separate your variables with a comma for them to be splitted when opened in any reader (like MSExcel).

```
var NBSref = textBox3.Text;
var Lenght = textBox1.Text;
var Width = textBox2.Text;

var separator = ",";

string csvpath = "FILE LOCATION";

StringBuilder csvcontentNew = new StringBuilder();
csvcontentNew.Append(NBSref + separator  + Lenght + separator  + Width);  // Try it like this

//String that will define CSV Location

File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvcontentNew.ToString());

textBox1.Clear();
textBox2.Clear();
textBox3.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel uses list separator set in 'Regional and language options' (Windows Control Panel). For the most regions it is comma but for such languages as Italian it is semicolon. 
Remeber that if you use the separator char in a cell as value you have to double quote your entire cell value (double quote, as the separator, can change in different regions).